# Why does CSS section:only-child selector not work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I was just messing around with the new HTML5 tags and pseudo selectors and noticed that the section:only-child selector appears not to work. I'm testing this on the latest version of Chrome (23.0).

My code is:

```
<section id="s1">
    <div id="div1">abc</div>
    <div id="div2">
        <span>first span</span>
        <span class="sp">second span</span>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div>first child test</div>
</section>​
```

and the CSS is:

```
section {
background-color: brown;
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
}

#s1 {
position: relative; 
background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5); 
border: 1px solid #000; width: 50%;
}

#div1 {
background-color: #0f0; 
position: relative;
}

#div2 {
background-color: #0ff; 
width: 200px; 
color: red;
}

#div2 .sp {
color: white;
text-decoration:line-through;
}

section:only-child {
color: yellow;

    }​
```

In theory, the text "first child test" should be yellow, because there is only one div on the second section, but it is not getting the yellow color for a font.

If I change the selector to div:only-child it'll work just fine.

You can see the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/KwzZs/3/

any reason why this is not working?

thanks

Comment: You don't appear to have any `section` elements which are `only-child`.  What are you expecting that rule to match?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This rule:

```
section:only-child
```

Matches a `section` element which is an `only-child`.

This rule (note the space):

```
section :only-child
```

Matches an element which is an `only-child` of a `section`.  [Is this what you expected](http://jsfiddle.net/KwzZs/4/)?

Comment: keep getting bitten by the space...thanks @robertc, that is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: To be more exact, if you want the only child **of `section`** you should use `>` instead of the space: `section > :only-child`. A space followed by `:only-child` means the only child of its parent, where the parent may or may not be `section`.

Answer (score 1):

`x:only-child` means that the `x` element *is* the only child of its parent - not that `x` has only one child.